# javascript `filter` statement throws type error

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I created a variable using javascript `filter` function.

```
let obj = pathSegments?.filter(function(item, idx, self) {
      return self.indexOf(item) == idx;
    })
console.log(obj); // (4) ['', 'product', 'brand', 'all']
```

I have created an array.
And we are going to display the conditional value of this array with the `filter` function.

```
  filter(element => element !== 'product' || element !== 'auth' )
```

We created a `product or auth` conditional using the filter function. But I get an error.

```
This condition will always return 'true' since the types '"product"' and '"auth"' have no overlap.
```

How do I change the filter conditional statement so that no error occurs?

Comment: `element` cannot be both `'product'` and `'auth'` at the same time, so expression `element !== 'product' || element !== 'auth'` will always be `true`. What you want might be `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: When `element = product`, then it is ***not*** `auth` therefore, the test passes. When `element = auth` then it is ***not*** `product`, therefore the test passes.

Comment: Better to use `() => !['product', 'auth'].includes(element)`